# How to access EntityManager in the Backing Component of a composite component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, composite-component

I made a composite component with a backing component:

Xhtml of the composite component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <composite:interface componentType="editorCompositeComponent">
        <!-- ...bunch of attributes... -->
        <composite:attribute name="content" type="java.lang.String" default="" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <!-- ... other components ... -->
        <p:editor widgetVar="editorWidget" value="#{cc.attrs.content}" width="600" maxlength="8000" />
        <p:commandButton action="#{cc.save(cc.attrs.caseId)}" value="Save" />
    </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

Backing component:

```
@FacesComponent("editorCompositeComponent")
public class EditorCompositeComponent extends UINamingContainer {

    private String content;
    // bunch of other variables

    public void save(String caseId) {

    MemoFile memoFile = new MemoFile();
    memoFile.setContent(content);
    memoFileService = new MemoFileService();
    // Normally this service would be Injected but Injection
    // isn't possible in @FacesComponent

    memoFileService.save(memoFile);
    // the save-method just calls EntityManager's merge etc.
    // It works well in all the ManagedBeans
    }
    // all the getters and setters
}
```

So, can't inject stuff and can't thereby find EntityManager, so how would one go about persisting the contents of the editor in composite component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency injection isn't supported in UI components. That's a bit too much of tight coupling of responsibilities. UI component instances aren't supposed to be managed by the container.

Your best bet is to create a separate request scoped managed bean for the task.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EditorCompositeBean {
    // ...
}
```

You could pass the composite component instance to its action method:

```
<p:commandButton ... action="#{editorCompositeBean.save(cc)}" />
```

Or use that bean as the model instead:

```
<composite:interface componentType="editorCompositeComponent">
    <composite:attribute name="value" type="com.example.EditorCompositeBean" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:editor ... value="#{cc.attrs.value.content}" />
    <p:commandButton ... action="#{cc.attrs.value.save}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually had it first with a ManagedBean as the backing bean of the component, but realized that because I want to have multiple instances of the same composite component in the same view I have to create a @FacesComponent for it.